# Ужасно медленно работают браузеры на Kali Linux в Virtual Box

Tags: linux, сеть, kali-linux

Ужасно медленно работают браузеры в Kali.Установил его на VB, но при открытии FireFox или тор они работают слишком медленно. С трудом загружается первая страница на Firefox, а в тор даже не подключается. Когда устанавливался тор, то установился он быстро. Что можно сделать?

P.S. Не кидайтесь камнями если что то не так.

Comment: `guest tools` поставил? А оперативы виртуалке сколько дал?

Comment: Если често то про guest tools Не слышал, а на виртуалке 8 гигабайт.

Comment: Я узнал про guest tools попытаюсь его установить. Извините за незнание.